# spark scala dataframe function over partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have 200 Mil rows with 1K groups looking like this

```
Group     X             Y             Z          Q           W
group1  0.054464866 0.002248819 0.299069804 0.763352879 0.395905106
group2  0.9986218   0.023649037 0.50762069  0.212225807 0.619571705
group1  0.839928517 0.290339179 0.050407454 0.75837838  0.495466007
group1  0.021003132 0.663366686 0.687928832 0.239132224 0.020848608
group1  0.393843426 0.006299292 0.141103438 0.858481036 0.715860852
group2  0.045960198 0.014858905 0.672267793 0.59750871  0.893646818
```

I want to run the same function (say `linear regression` of `X` on `[X, Z, Q, W]`) for each of the groups. I could have done `Window.partition` etc. but I have my own function. At the moment, I do the following:

```
df.select("Group").distinct.collect.toList.foreach{group => 
val dfGroup = df.filter(col("Group")===group
dfGroup.withColumn("res", myUdf(col("X"), col("Y"), col("Z"), col("Q"), col("W"))}
```

Wonder if there is a better way to do?

Comment: an UDF acts on a single row, so why don't you just use your UDF on the original dataframe, there is no point in just selecting one Group.

Comment: If you want to do linear regression (which involves all records for a group), I would do something like `df.repartition($"Group").mapPartitions{rows => rows.toSeq.groupBy(row => row.getAs[String]("Group")).mapValues(...)}`

Answer (score 1):

You have minimum two options depending what you prefer: DataFrame or Dataset.

### DataFrame with UDAF

```
df
  .groupBy("group")
  .agg(myUdaf(col("col1"), col("col2")))
```

where `myUdaf` is UDAF

Here you can find example how to implement UDAF: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html

### Dataset

You can use `groupByKey` and `mapGroups` transformations from Dataset API:

```
ds
  .groupByKey(_.group)
  .mapGroups{case (group, values) =>
    (group, aggregator(values))
  }
```

where `aggregator` is Scala function responsible for aggregating collection of objects.

If you don't need aggregating you can just map `values` using `map` transformation, example:

```
values.map(v => fun(...))
```